# How to auto increment primary key value dependent on another primary key

Tags: mysql, database

Kinda hard to describe in the title. I have a pair of primary keys "unique_id" and "user_id" I want to auto increment the unique_id for a particular user_id.

If I'm adding 2 rows with a user_id = 1, then I want the unique_id to auto increment 2 times for the user_id = 1.

If I then add a row with a user_id = 2, then I want the unique_id to start at 1.

If I then add a row where the user_id = 1 again, I want it to increment the value of the unique_id attached to user_id 1

Comment: You use triggers for this and you handle incrementing manually. Your title also mentions "auto increment" - it's unclear whether you're referring to `auto_increment` mechanics of MySQL or "automatic incrementing" as a concept. To me, this looks like an XY problem. Your best bet would be to expand your question with table schema and what particular problem you're solving with this perceived solution that you need help with.

Comment: What you describe is not a unique ID. It#s more like a counter field. First of all, an ID never gets changed (otherwise it is not an ID).